# Access files with wildcard filename in directory structure

Tags: python, file

I have the following directory structure

```
top_folder
  secondary_folder1
    file1.txt
  secondary_folder2
    deep_folder
      file2.txt
    file3.txt
    file4.html
  file5.txt
  file6.txt
```

I would like to access all the `.txt` files that is in a folder within `top_folder` (but not in any deeper folder). For example, here it is `file1.txt` and `file3.txt`. Is this possible using Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) module:

```
import glob
import os
files = []
for x in os.listdir(path_to_top_folder):
    if os.path.isdir(x):
        for fil in glob.glob("{0}/*.txt".format(x)):
            files += [os.path.split(fil)[-1]]
print files
```

or :

```
import glob
import os
files = [os.path.split(x)[-1] for x in  glob.glob(path to tip_folder/*/*.txt)]
```

help on `os.path.split`:

```
>>> os.path.split?
Definition: os.path.split(p)
Docstring:
Split a pathname.  Returns tuple "(head, tail)" where "tail" is
everything after the final slash.  Either part may be empty.
```

Comment: Wouldn't that return `file5.txt` and `file6.txt` in this example, which is not what I want?

Comment: Should it be `path to top_folder/*/*.txt`?

Comment: @PaulS. I've updated my solution, yes that will work too but to get just file names you may have to use `os.path.split`.

Comment: Thank you, would you mind explaining what `os.path.split(x)[-1]` does?

Comment: `os.path.split` splits a path into two parts  head and tail, where "tail" is
everything after the final slash. for example : `os.path.split("/home/foo/abc.txt")` will return a tuple `('/home/foo', 'abc.txt')` and I used -1 to get the last item from this tuple.